# [React]: rendering through this.props.children always unmounts and mounts all children instead of just re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

i have created an accordion in react that has expand collapse functionality. 
render:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label className="label">
            { this.props.label }
        </label>
    </div>
    <div style={{ display: !!this.state.expanded ? "block" : "none" }}>
{ this.props.children } </div>
</div>
```

I call it in  something like:

```
<Accordion>
    <MyComponent1/>
    <MyComponent2/>
    <MyComponent3/>
</Accordion>
```

but everytime accordion is expanded/ collapsed, child components are mounted unmounted. because of this they lose any data/state of their own and i have to keep everything in  
also  does not re-render when expand collapse happen.

shouldnt child components just re-render and not unmount and mount again when collapse-expand happens. Is there a way to achieve the same. 
i dont want  to keep state of each individual child Compoent

@Drew Schuster: whole code-

export class Accordion extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        expanded: false
    }
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    let className = My_String_Util.format("chevron-", this.state.expanded ? "down" : "right");
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={ this._toggle }>
                <label className={ className }  />
                <label className="label"> { this.props.label } </label>
            </div>
            <If condition={ this.state.expanded }>
                <div style={{
                    display: !!this.state.expanded ? "block" : "none"
                }}>{ this.props.children }</div>
            </If>
        </div>
    );
}

private _toggle = (): void => {
    this.setState({
        expanded: !this.state.expanded
    });
}
```

}

ParentComponent:

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    <Accordion label="Sample Accordion2" expanded={true} >
        <MyChildComponent
                        sampleProp={"aa"}
                        stringParentProp={"initial string"}/>
                    <label>"Hello World3"</label>

                    </Accordion>
}
```

MyChildComponent:

```
constructor(props) {
this.state = {
stateString = this.props.stringParentProp
}
}
render(): JSX.Element {
<div onClick={this._changeLabel}>
    <label>this.state.stateString</label>
</div>
}

private _changeLabel() {
this.setState = {
stateString = this.state.stateString + "x";
}
}
```

this should add 'x' everytime we click on childcomponent to its label. which works. but when we collapse and then expand again, label get reset to "initial string"

Comment: Can you post more code? The code you've put up so far should work as expected, it might be more helpful to see the entire accordion component and where it is being called.

Comment: @DrewSchuster added the code in question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as included has some errors that prevent it from compiling. I removed some code not needed to reproduce this error and now have a working solution at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/dtschust/pen/ALKkQo). Code also included below, I used React.createClass instead of extending React.Component but you certainly don't have to.:

```
const Accordion = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { expanded: false }
  },

  _toggle: function () {
      this.setState({
          expanded: !this.state.expanded
      });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={ this._toggle }>
                <label className={ className }  />
                <label className="label"> { this.props.label } </label>
            </div>
            <div style={{
                display: !!this.state.expanded ? "block" : "none"
              }}>{ this.props.children }</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

const MyChildComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { stateString: this.props.stringParentProp}
  },
  _changeLabel: function () {
    this.setState(
      {
      stateString: this.state.stateString + "x"
    })
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._changeLabel}>
        <label>{this.state.stateString}</label>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const Parent = () => {
    return (
      <Accordion label="Sample Accordion2" expanded={true} >
          <MyChildComponent
            sampleProp="aa"
            stringParentProp="initial string"/>
          <label>"Hello World3"</label>
      </Accordion>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

Comment: it always unmounts the component for me. i want something in which component is just rerendered

Comment: In the code I provided above, the component is not unmounted

Comment: There's a lot in your code snippet that isn't working properly, like in MyChildComponent `<label>this.state.stateString</label>` should be `<label>{this.state.stateString}</label>` or else your label will literally only say "this.state.stateString". What's probably giving you the issue is your use of `this.setState` in MyChildComponent. Shouldn't be `this.setState = ...`, should be `this.setState({stateString: this.state.stateString + "x"})`